# como recuperar los datos enviados por post en php?

Tags: php, html5

tengo un formulario y cuando le doy enviar este se conecta a un archivo php donde hace la inserción de los datos,luego aparece un alerta que dice correcta inserción ,y me regresa al formulario,todo bien hasta ahi lo malo es que cuando regresa al formulario los campos se borrado como puedo hacer para que no se borres los datos del formulario,gracias

codigo html del formulario

```
     <div id="formulario_esquema">

  <form action="" method="POST">
             <legend>Primera fase: <?php echo $apellidop.' '.$apellidom.' '.$nombre.'/'.$nro_caso.'/'.$tipo_tratamiento;?></legend>

<?php 

  $resultado_tipotuberculosis = mysqli_query($conexion,"SELECT * FROM localizacion_enfermedad");
  $resultado_localizacion = mysqli_query($conexion,"SELECT * FROM especificacion_localizacion");
  $resultado_comorbilidad = mysqli_query($conexion,"SELECT * FROM comorbilidad")
 ?>

  <div class="campo_formularios">
             <input type="hidden"  name ="dni" id="dni" value=<?php echo $dni?>>
             <input type="hidden" name="nro_caso" id="nro_caso" value=<?php echo $nro_caso?>>
               <input type="hidden" name="nombre" id="nombre" value=<?php echo $nombre?>>
             <input type="hidden" name="apellidom" id="apellidom" value=<?php echo $apellidom?>>
             <input type="hidden" name="apellidop" id="apellidop" value=<?php echo $apellidop?>>
             <input type="hidden" name="tipo_tratamiento" id="tipo_tratamiento" value=<?php echo $tipo_tratamiento?>>

              <select class="tipo_tuberculosis" id="tipo_tuberculosis" name="tipo_tuberculosis">
               <option value="0" disabled selected>Tipo de Tuberculosis</option>
                  <?php  
                   while ($rowtitu = $resultado_tipotuberculosis -> fetch_array()) 
                   {

                   ?>

          <option value="<?php echo $rowtitu['cod_localizacion_enf']; ?>"><?php echo $rowtitu['nombre_localizacion'];  ?></option>
          <?php
               }

            ?>

              </select>




              <select class="localizacion" id="localizacion" name="localizacion">
              <option value="0" disabled selected>Localizacion</option>
              <?php
                       while($roweslo = $resultado_localizacion-> fetch_array())
                       {
                     ?>
                        <option value="<?php echo $roweslo['cod_esp_loc']; ?>"><?php echo $roweslo['nombre_especificacion_loc'];  ?></option>

                        <?php 
                             }
                         ?>

              </select>

              <select class="comorbilidad" id="comobilidad"  name="comobilidad" onchange="mostrartabla()">
               <option value="0" disabled selected >Comorbilidad</option>
                   <?php
                       while($rowcom = $resultado_comorbilidad -> fetch_array())
                       {
                     ?>

                     <option value="<?php echo $rowcom['cod_comobilidad']; ?>"><?php echo $rowcom['nombre_comorbilidad'];  ?></option>

                     <?php
                          }
                       ?>



              </select>

              <div class="fecha_ini">
                   <label>Feche inicio</label><input id="infechaini" type="date" name="infechaini" onblur="obtenerfechafinf1();" style="height:30px;">  
              </div>

             <div id="fecha_fin">
             </div>

   </div> 

          <div id="tabla_tratamiento">

          </div>    


  <div class='botones'>
          <div class="btnenviarf2">
             <input type='submit' id='btnenviar' class='btnenviar' name='btnenviar' value='GUARDAR FASE 1' onclick="this.form.action='guardarf1.php'; this.form.submit();">
          </div>
          <div class="pasarf2">    
             <input type='submit' id='pasar' class='pasar' name='pasar' value='PASAR A FASE 2' onclick="this.form.action='esquemaf2.php'; this.form.submit();">
          </div>
    </div>

  </form> 
</div>
```

codigo php

```
 <?php
     include '../conexionbd.php';

    date_default_timezone_set('America/Bogota');


    $dni = $_POST["dni"];
    $cod_loc_enf=$_POST["tipo_tuberculosis"];
    $cod_comorbilidad=$_POST["comobilidad"];
    $cod_esp_loc=$_POST["localizacion"];
    $nro_caso=$_POST["nro_caso"];
    $cod_fase ='1';
    $flag_fase1='1';
    $flag_fase2='0';
    $fecha_inicio=$_POST["infechaini"];
    $fecha_fin=$_POST["fechafin"];


    $consulta_codtramiento = "SELECT cod_tratamiento FROM tratamiento where cod_loc_enf='$cod_loc_enf' and cod_esp_loc='$cod_esp_loc' and cod_comorbilidad='$cod_comorbilidad'";
    $consultar_pacf1 ="SELECT flag_ver_fase1 FROM det_pac_tra where flag_ver_fase1='1' AND dni='$dni'";

    $resultado_pacf1 = mysqli_query($conexion,$consultar_pacf1) or die(mysqli_error($conexion));

    if(mysqli_num_rows($resultado_pacf1)>0){
        echo'
          <script>
        alert("EL PACIENTE YA SE ENCUENTRA REGISTRADO EN PRIMERA FASE");
        window.history.go(-1);
          </script>
        ';
        exit;
    }
    //echo $consulta_codtramiento;

    $resultado_codtratamiento = mysqli_query($conexion,$consulta_codtramiento) or die(mysqli_error($conexion));
    while($fila = $resultado_codtratamiento->fetch_array()) 
    {

        $cod_tratamiento=$fila["cod_tratamiento"];

    }

    //echo $cod_tratamiento;




    $insertar_dettratamiento ="INSERT INTO det_pac_tra(dni,nro_caso,cod_tratamiento,cod_fase,flag_ver_fase1,flag_ver_fase2,fecha_inicio_fase1,fecha_fin_fase1) values('$dni','$nro_caso','$cod_tratamiento','$cod_fase','$flag_fase1','$flag_fase2','$fecha_inicio','$fecha_fin')";



    $resultado = mysqli_query($conexion,$insertar_dettratamiento) or die(mysqli_error($conexion));

    if($resultado){

        //secho $insertar_dettratamiento;

        echo "<script>
         alert('LA FASE 1 SE ENCUETRA REGISTRADA CORRECTAMENTE');
       window.history.go(-1);

         </script>
        ";


    }else{
    echo "<script>
     alert('Ocurio un error lo sentimos');
     window.history.go(-1);
     document.getElementById('tipo_tuberculosis').value=0;
     document.getElementById('comobilidad').value=0;
     document.getElementById('localizacion').value=0;

     </script>
    ";
}

mysqli_close($conexion);




  ?>
```

Comment: agrega esta linea al inicio import_request_variables("gp", "");

Comment: Debes de poner la dirección de destino en el action, si no jamás llegarán allí los datos.

Comment: import_request_variables:

Advertencia
Esta función ha sido declarada OBSOLETA desde PHP 5.3.0 y ELIMINADA a partir de PHP 5.4.0.

Comment: Lo mejor para hacer lo que quieres es enviar el formulario por medio de Ajax. De ese modo envías los datos al servidor en background, sin necesidad de moverte del formulario, pulsando sólo un botón. Y si quieres mostrar algún mensaje sin moverte de tu página de formulario, mostrar datos recuperados de la llamada hecha al servidor, etc... puedes hacerlo perfectamente.

Comment: si eso estaba pensando,aunque mi nivel de ajax es basico si hice eso q dices, una pregunta como pasaria los valores por post para no mover mucho el codigo que tengo en el php?, o necesariamente tengo q usar el get en el ajax , como te decia es muy basico mi ajax gracias

Comment: extract($_REQUEST);

Answer (score 2):

En PHP dispones de tres arrays para recoger los datos que envíes:

- $_GET para los parámetros que vayan en la misma URL
- $_POST para los parámetros enviados por post (como tu caso)
- y $_REQUEST que es una mezcla de las anteriores.

Son "superglobales", así que están disponibles en cualquier ámbito.

Para mantener el valor que se envió debes poner el "option" que corresponda como "selected", no todos ellos, ejemplo para el primer "select":

```
<option value="<?php echo $rowtitu['cod_localizacion_enf'] . ($cod_loc_enf == $rowtitu['cod_localizacion_enf'] ? '" selected="selected' : ''); ?>">
```

Y quita el "selected" del primero, si no hay ninguno seleccionado se selecciona el primero por omisión.